# Have confusion about the accessing null's next property?

Tags: javascript, singly-linked-list

I am learning DS with javascript.
While implementing linked list push() method in ll my mentor wrote code.
But I am unable to understand a part of that.

Here in SinglyLinkedList class I have initialize this.tail = null but in push method's else block trying to access the property next  | this.tail.next = newNode | which doesn't exist ....but still program is working properly.

Pls explain me this... Why

```
class node {


constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
class SinglyLinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  push(val) {
    var newNode = new node(val);
    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = newNode;
      this.tail = this.head;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode;
    }
    this.length++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice that `this.tail` is null if and only if `this.head` is also null

Comment: sorry for asking that silly question.

Comment: Thank u so much